# Does a scope propagate through a foreach loop?

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

I wanted to draw a bunch of circles using a `\foreach` using the `even odd fill` rule.

If I do:

```
\documentclass{standalone}\input tikz\begin{document}\tikz{

\begin{scope}[red,even odd rule]
\fill(1,1)circle(1);
\fill(2,2)circle(2);
\end{scope}

}\end{document}
```

[image: Image 1]

I get the desired effect, however if I do

```
\documentclass{standalone}\input tikz\begin{document}\tikz{

\begin{scope}[fill=red,even odd rule]
\foreach\i in {1,2}{
\fill(\i,\i)circle(\i);
}
\end{scope}

}\end{document}
```

[image: Image 2]

The properties of the scope no longer effect my `\draw`.  Is there someway to get the scope to propagate through the `\foreach` loop?

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @MöbiusStripMall: Please make sure they actually compile. In the second one, you are using `\i` as the loop variable and then atte,pting to access `\x`.  Also, please include the image that you get form the two versions.

Comment: The `even odd rule` only has an effect on a _single_ path. Ex: `\fill[even odd rule] (1,1) circle(1) (2,2) circle(2);`

Comment: The first snippet does not produce the claimed output.

Comment: @AndrewSwann That is correct.  I must have made a mistake at some point causing it to appear that it was outputting that image.  The question is ultimately founded on the preconception that the mistake was proper behavior and should probably be closed.

Comment: @MöbiusStripMall You can also delete your own question, there is a button below on the left, close to `share edit close`...

Comment: @CarLaTeX unfortunately I have insufficient reputation to delete a question that already has answers.

Comment: It doesn't matter, the Community has already put it on hold :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX Oh I didn't see that people had already done that.  Should I delete this question now that it has been closed?  Usually I would let voters delete or not delete it fi necessary, but I am not acquainted very well with this site's culture.  I do hope to revise this once I understand what is going on.

Comment: No, you shouldn't. Since it has already been answered, I don't think  it will be deleted neither by the Community. However, you can edit it whenever you like.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve the desired result using a loop as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[red,even odd rule]
    \fill
    \foreach\i in {1,2}{
    (\i,\i) circle(\i)}
    ;
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am getting identical results:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[draw=blue, ultra thick, fill=red!20,even odd rule]
        \filldraw (1,1) circle(1);
        \filldraw (2,2) circle(2);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[draw=blue, ultra thick, fill=red!20,even odd rule]
        \foreach \i in {1,2} {
            \filldraw (\i,\i) circle(\i);
        }
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm... Something very strange is going on for me.  I will delete the question until I understand what exactly is happening.  Thank you.

Comment: @MöbiusStripMall: There must be some version problem. Add `\listfiles` and include the output that lists the version of each package.

Comment: I don't think it is.  I get the same output as you now but 5 minutes ago when I compiled the images for this question I got different results.  I am really confused right now.  I think however that my question is ultimately founded on some misconception or error on my part.